# Why does this not reset all controls to original position?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have created a panel called StatePanel that inherets from Panel class, yet has a few extra fields such as OrigXPosition and OrigYPosition (which are initialized at the beginning). These can be dragged and dropped into groupboxes from a tabPage. But, I'd like to have a reset button that whenever I pressed it, it goes through each and every groupbox and takes each and every statepanel to move back to it's original position in the tab control. To accomplish such I came up with this code :

```
    private void ResetStatePanels()
    {
        foreach (Control groupBx in tabPageRegions.Controls){
            if (groupBx.Name.Substring(0, 2) == "gb")
            {
                foreach (Control c in groupBx.Controls)
                {
                    StatePanel sp1 = c as StatePanel;
                    tabPageRegions.Controls.Add(sp1);
                    sp1.Location = new Point(sp1.OrigXPosition, sp1.OrigYPosition);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However when I run that code, every other statepanel or so in each groupbox ends up moving back to it's original position. It's VERY strange, because not only that, but if I press the button that calls that function a couple more times, every time I press it more and more move back to the original position until all of them are there. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have added a youtube video to show the behavior better : https://youtu.be/-WlJoymLcSs

Comment: You are modifying the collection you are iterating.  The Controls.Add() call *removes* it from the groupbox.  In effect your foreach loop skips every other control.  You need to iterate backwards or make a copy of the Controls collection.  Like `foreach (var c in groupBx.Controls.OfType<StatePanel>.ToList())`.  Also helps prevent your code crashing with a NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your `foreach (Control c in groupBx.Controls)`, you are removing elements in a collection while iterating, that is an anti-pattern.

One solution is to create an another collection beforehand:

```
            StatePanel[] panels = groupBx.Controls.OfType<StatePanel>().ToArray();
            foreach (StatePanel sp1 in panels)
            {
                tabPageRegions.Controls.Add(sp1);
                sp1.Location = new Point(sp1.OrigXPosition, sp1.OrigYPosition);
            }
```

Comment: You are exactly right. Overlooked that entirely. Thank you!